# Devtools of Chrome/Edge are "jumping" to the sources tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools

One thing is annoying me already a longer time and I could not find out how to change this.
Whenever I am developing my web apps, the dev tools of Chrome always jump to the "sources" tab automatically (in german: "Quellen" like in my gif animation.)
This tab is not interesting for me, because I am debugging with VS Code already.
I want to see the output of the console or the network tab *all the time*.

But the browser always jumps there and I always have to go back to my wanted tab if I am reloading the page.

I demonstrated this behaviour here with a gif animation:

[image]

Any idea how to change this annoying behaviour? Or is there a good reason for this?

Comment: Looks like a bug in devtools. You can report it on https://crbug.com if it's not reported yet and not fixed in Chrome Canary (it can be installed separately in addition to your main Chrome).

Comment: Hard to believe - this behaviour is there since a long time already. Other developers must have noticed already... its super annoying...

Comment: Check the `Breakpoints` panel. It happens when you set a breakpoint, you can remove the breakpoint or go to devtools options and disable this behavior.

Comment: I do not have any breakpoints at all... what do you mean with "disable this behavior"? Where can I do that?

Comment: In options: https://puu.sh/IjwYH/1bfb5c5749.png

Comment: This behaviour will also happen if you are debugging via vscode and have a breakpoint defined in vscode (as opposed to defined in the chrome/edge debugger itself). Remove the breakpoints from both chrome/edge and vscode.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I had the same issue. Solved doing :
DevTools options -> sources -> uncheck "Focus Sources panel when triggering a breakpoint"

Comment: I'm using the VSCode debugger and Edge DevTools and when I have DevTools open it still gets focus even with this setting unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Even though @Devip answer fixed the annoyance of source tab automatically being focused, it did not fix actual issue - source tab would still automatically open and close files.

In my case the issue was that I had breakpoints set in VSCode itself, rather than DevTools. (not sure if it's relevant, these breakpoints were `unbound` because I was working on a userscript, which can't be mapped to the browser). The DevTools would simply flash `debugger paused` message for a split of a second and open a file in the source tab. In some cases it would open and immediately close files. I couldn't figure out why these files were opened...

##### My solution was to remove ALL breakpoints in VSCode and restart debugger session.